# Open PDF from MS Access, using windows forms in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am developing an app in vb.net and MS Access. At first, after many hours I used some sources to put a code together to open a pdf file from the db. The code works. But when I lunch the pdf from the application, it creates a pdf file in the root folder. So now I have it in the db as binary(OLEObjects) and in the root folder. I only need it to be in one place. Here is the code:

```
    Dim strSqll As String
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BCInventory.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
    conn.Open()


    strSqll = "Select filename from pdf WHERE PR = '" & pr & "' AND Year = '" & year & "'"

    Dim sqlCmdd As New OleDbCommand(strSqll, conn)

    Dim r As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCmdd.ExecuteReader()

    If Not r.HasRows Then Exit Sub

    Do While r.Read()
        fname = r.GetString(0)
    Loop
    conn.Close()

       Try
            Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BCInventory.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
            con.Open()
            Dim strSql As String = "Select File from pdf WHERE PR = '" & pr & "' AND Year = '" & year & "' AND fileType='" & ftype & "'"

            Dim sqlCmd As New OleDbCommand(strSql, con)

            Dim fileData As Byte() = DirectCast(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

            Dim sTempFileName As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Purchase Orders scans" & "\" & fname

            If Not fileData Is Nothing Then
                Using fs As New FileStream(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
                    fs.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)
                    fs.Flush()
                    fs.Close()
                End Using
                ShellEx(Me.Handle, "Open", fname, "", "", 10)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: What are you asking for? You're telling an application to open a file, that application more than likely was written in such a way that it can open PDF files but nothing from a database... So what is it that you want to do exactly? Can't you get the file from the database into the system's temp folder to have it cleaned up automatically or so that you can clean it up when it's no longer used?

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear. I wanted to get stop storing the pdf inside my db, instead I wanted to have all the pdf file in a one folder and in the db just have a path to that folder. I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strSqll As String
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BCInventory.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
conn.Open()


strSqll = "Select filename from pdf WHERE PR = '" & pr & "' AND Year = '" & year & "'"

Dim sqlCmdd As New OleDbCommand(strSqll, conn)

Dim r As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCmdd.ExecuteReader()

If Not r.HasRows Then Exit Sub

Do While r.Read()
    fname = r.GetString(0)
Loop
conn.Close()

    Try
         If Len(Trim(fname)) = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("There is no file attached", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                txtpr.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            End If
         ShellEx(Me.Handle, "Open", fname, "", "", 10)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```